# yarn start updating my development server after each input change instead of only after i save

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, visual-studio-code, yarnpkg

I think I may have accidentally changed some setting that caused it to do this. Before, it would only update the page if I save the document.

How do I revert this?

I am using VS Code.

Comment: You probably have autosave on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check VS Code Setting:

For control over Auto Save , open User or Workspace settings and find the associated settings: files. autoSave : Can have the values: off - to disable auto save.  File > AutoSave. Checked?